# How many headings can I use in my html structure [SEO]

Tags: html, seo

How many headings `<H1,H2,...>` can I use in my html structure **to be friendly with SEO** ?

I have main page and i don't have paragraph `<P>` tag in main page bu I have many links with titles.. actually it's movie guide..

My structure now is:

```
<H1>Site Title</H1> #1
<h2>movies links</h2> #20 with links
<h3>Section names</h3>
```

Is good or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one H1, maybe a few H2, then go bananas with H3, H4, H5, H6.

Answer (score 0):

I would say h1-h3 is fine to go with seo - it is also explained here - http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-checklist-using-page-headings-correctly/7723/

Don't forget to base your headings on the keywords too